# Understanding the Cauchy Convergence proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

The following is from the Fitzpatrick's Calculus textbook :

[image]

I have a question regarding the last 3 lines of the proof above.

By definition, to prove that ${\{a_n}\}$ converges to a it is sufficient *only* to find an index $N$ such that for a given $\epsilon >0$, $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$. In the lines of the proof it seems that $N$ is the one which Eq. 9.1. holds and "Now choose any index $k$ such that $k \ge K$ and $n_k \ge N$" is a consequence. It is logical to be so, since the begining of the last three lines (l.h.s.) depends on $n$; but, in the middle $n_k$ appears and it must have such a value that both $|a_n-a_{n_k}|$ and $|a-a_{n_k}|$ be less than $\epsilon /2$ which contradicts the definition of limit by only an index $N$.

In other words (in the last 3 lines of the proof above), first line depends only on $n$, then $n_k$ appears in the second line which is not fictitious since *it determines* the final inequality of $< \epsilon$ .

I believe that this proof "seems" correct but it is not a rigorous and correct for the mentioned logical impairment; or maybe I am wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure where's the logical gap you speak of. For $n\ge N$, we want to prove that $|a-a_n|<\epsilon$. So we pick up a suitable $n_k$ (which presumably depends on $n$) which is "close enough" to both of $a_n$ and $a$, which lets us conclude. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Ankoganit, About the last 3 lines: if $n\ge N$ and $n_k<N$ still the first two lines hold but the third line may not hold. That's the problem!  So we couldn't garantee $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for that $N$.

Comment: What may be confusing is that in the last paragraph we are choosing one particular $k$. Suppose in the last paragraph you replace "$k$" with "$k_0$", For example $k_0$ could be the least $l$ such that $l\geq K$ and $n_l\geq N.$

Comment: Another way to see that $(a_n)_n$ coverges to $a$:  Suppose  it didn't. Then for some $r>0$ there would be arbitrarily large $m$ for which $|a-a_m|>r.$  But there are also arbitrarily large values of $n_k$ for which $|a-a_{n_k}|<r/10^{1000}.$ This implies  $|a_m-a_{n_k}|>r/2$ for arbitrarily large values of $\min (m, n_k)$ , but that  makes the sequence $(a_n)_n$  non-Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is correct. The sequence $(a_{n})$ being Cauchy gives the $N$. Convergence of a subsequence $(a_{n_{k}})$ of $(a_{n})$ to $a$ gives the $K$; for here $n_{k}$ is determined by $k$. Then the author manages to use these to bound $|a_{n_{k}} -
 a_{n}|$ and $|a_{n_{k}} - a|$ simultaneously. So how to do this? Note that $n_{k}$ can be arbitrarily large as $k$ increases; this is implied by the definition of a subsequence of a sequence. So all he has to do is to consider any of those $k \geq K$, which certainly exist, such that $n_{k} \geq N$, which also exists. Now for all $k \geq K$ such that $n_{k} \geq N$ we have $|a_{n_{k}}-a|, |a_{n_{k}} - a_{n}| < \varepsilon/2$

Comment: About the last 3 lines: if $n\ge N$ and $n_k<N$ still the first two lines hold but the third line may not hold. That's the problem!  So we couldn't garantee $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for that $N$.

Comment: Hi please note that $n_{k}$ is determined by $k$; so taking $k$ large enough such that $k \geq K$ and $n_{k} \geq N$ (as I analyzed to you, this can be done) solves the problem :). From your words I suppose you would be confused by the symbols employed. There are two kinds of symbols: dummy variables and free variables. A dummy variable is typically the one that appears along with quantifiers such as "for all" or "there is some".